# Can the cross entropy cost function be used with tanh?

Tags: neural-networks

I know the cross entropy function can be used as the cost function, if the activation function is *logistic* function: i.e.: $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$

However, I just wonder:

Can the cross entropy cost function be used with many other activation functions, such as *tanh*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can, as long as we use some normalizor (e.g. softmax) to ensure that the final output values are in between 0 and 1 and add up to 1.

If you're doing binary classification and only use one output value, only normalizing it to be between 0 and 1 will do.

Update
As mentioned by Sycorax, depending on what procedure you use to shifting and rescaling tanh back to [0,1], you could end up with a logistic unit again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36440463/3041068).

Comment: tanh output between -1 and +1, so can it not be used with cross entropy cost function?

Comment: @xmllmx not really, [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) requires the output can be interpreted as probability values, so we need some normalization for that.

Comment: Depending on what procedure you use to shifting and rescaling $\tanh$ back to $[0,1]$, you could end up with a logistic unit again -- since the logistic unit is just a shifted-rescaled $\tanh$ unit.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary goal isn't to interpret values as probability values, but simply to find a "good" cost function for a tanh activation, in the sense that the neural network will learn faster the more "wrong" it is, then I believe that this may work:

[image: thanh_cross_entropy]

or, in python form:

```py
def C(y, a):
    return  -.5 * ( (1-y)*log(1-a) + (1+y)*log(1+a) ) + log(2)
```

More formally - this will give a cost function whose derivative is proportional to the error - ie, satisfy these two equations:

[image: dC/da]

[image: dC/db]

These are equations (71) and (72) from here: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#the_cross-entropy_cost_function - thanks to Michael Nielsen for this great resource!

As others have noted, since it doesn't really have a probablity interpretation, I don't know if this formula can really be called a "cross-entropy" function for tanh... but it should be a "good" choice for a cost function for a tanh activation... or at least better than mean-squared-error!

As a caveat, though - I'm relatively new to all this, so feel free to point out if I've made any obvious errors!

---

EDIT: I made some code (using keras) to test the performance of this cost function, versus mean-squared-error, and my tests show nearly double the performance!

Here's the gist / code:
https://gist.github.com/elrond79/a016230229322f3ba2b46a99ff0b4e7c

... and here were my results:

0.00850945741317                                                                                                                                                          0.0121004378641                                                                                                                                                           0.0144485289499                                                                                                                                                           0.0259487312062                                                                                                                                                           0.011714946112                                                                                                                                                            0.0103978548285                                                                                                                                                           0.0308227941615                                                                                                                                                           0.0070723194485                                                                                                                                                           0.0142580815076                                                                                                                                                           0.0160464689688                                                                                                                                                           0.013335006552                                                                                                                                                            0.00783108495935                                                                                                                                                          0.01220898181                                                                                                                                                             0.0173612970037                                                                                                                                                           0.0276861919335                                                                                                                                                           0.0137742581066                                                                                                                                                           0.0227281911188                                                                                                                                                           0.0108267272463                                                                                                                                                           0.0138346472817                                                                                                                                                           0.0110096849345

average: 0.01509578457033614

maes:                                                                                                                 0.00782039967299                                                                                                                                                          0.0102608616831                                                                                                                                                           0.00747869220265                                                                                                                                                          0.0106438063825                                                                                                                                                           0.00730774874144                                                                                                                                                          0.0106295737387                                                                                                                                                           0.00770924169349                                                                                                                                                          0.014159071813                                                                                                                                                            0.00763049735583                                                                                                                                                          0.00902260985951                                                                                                                                                          0.00602617238736                                                                                                                                                          0.0103817401882                                                                                                                                                           0.0108806326851                                                                                                                                                           0.00879056832034                                                                                                                                                          0.00743713011182                                                                                                                                                          0.00648508079659                                                                                                                                                          0.00660474073891                                                                                                                                                          0.00766924505766                                                                                                                                                          0.00738797156683                                                                                                                                                          0.00708367751452

average: 0.008570473125530578

Not conclusive, obviously, but certainly suggestive that this will give better results than MSE for tanh activations!

EDIT 2: Realized the custom cost function was also causing the graph to evaluate slower, so # of iterations wasn't necessarily a fair comparison. Altered the test to compare error when running for the same amount of time, and then mse outperforms this tanh-cross-entropy-like cost. Still, it's possible it could be useful for more complicated graphs, when the additional time is a lower percentage of the total.

Comment: In my opinion, if the dC/dz contains other terms other than (a-y), it usually makes the gradient to be biased based on the a value, which is unwanted side-effect. Thus there is an optimal C which is `integrate (a-y)/g'(z(a))`. In this case it will be 1/2 ((-1 + y) log(1 - x) - (1 + y) log(1 + x)). Your edit2 seems strange. Because evaluation does not require to compute C at all and in real inference application we always turn off the loss evaluation.